# QGIS 3.22.8-Bialowieza Digitising using Auto Trace but line not following vertices correctly

Tags: qgis, digitizing, trace

I am trying to draw a polygon between existing polygons but it does not follow the vertices correctly even though I tried the snapping and enable tracing options. A screen shot is shown with the snapping/tracing settings.

[image: Auto trace]

Comment: I would suggest that you would find it easier to use topological editing with the avoid overlap setting in the snapping options, and then drawing your polygon so it intially overlaps the edges of the polygons you were going to trace.  It should on finishing then remove the overlaps and match the other polygon vertices.  The trace tool in QGIS is a little funky, you still have to put vertices every so often especially where there is a sharp directional change and it may still need a bit of cleanup afterwards.  It takes some practice to use well.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Appreciate your response. I tried but now it snaps automatically to other polygons also. It used to work smoothly with other polygon shape files but I came to experience this for the first time with this polygon shapefile shown above. WIll try figure it out. Otherwise will go the tedious way - just digitize following the nodes.